# How to use cuda with LSP-clangd

Tags: c++, cuda, sublimetext3, clangd

I want to use sublime text as my c++ editor.

I added LSP-clangd in the editor. I generate some `compile_commands.json` and clangd works on almost every files in my project but not with cuda files.

I saw in [clangd FAQ](https://clangd.llvm.org/faq#does-clangd-support-cuda) that we must ensure :

1. *that our editor plugin is enabling clangd when CUDA files are open (e.g. enabling for extension *.cu)*. **I didn't found any parameters in LSP-clangd settings to add some file extensions.**
2. *make sure that clangd understands these are CUDA files (e.g. by extension *.cu or adding the clang flag -xcuda)*. **Where should I add these flags? In `compile_commands.json`?**
3. *set the path to your cuda installation if it isn’t detected, by adding the clang flag --cuda-path=...* **Where should I specify this path? I tried using command `clang --cuda-path=my/cuda/path` but it returns me `clang: error; no input files`**

Have you any idea to solve one of these 3 problems ? or did someone suceed to use cuda with clangd in sublime text ?

Comment: For #2 and #3, I think the best place to specify both the `-xcuda` flag (note: I believe this is only needed if your CUDA files _don't_ have a CUDA-specific extension such as `*.cu`), and the `--cuda-path` flag is a [clangd config file](https://clangd.llvm.org/config.html) using `CompileFlags:` `Add:`. These flags will be added to the flags from `compile_commands.json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @HighCommander4, I solve this issue by adding a clang config file to my project. Moreover, I found an [issue](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/issues/125) on clangd github that shares a similar problem.

Here is the `.clangd` configuration file that I use for my project :

```yaml
CompileFlags:
  Add:
    - --cuda-path=C://Program Files//NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit//CUDA//v12.1
    - -LC://Program Files//NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit//CUDA//v12.1//lib
    - -IC://Program Files//NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit//CUDA//v12.1//include
```